# Animation not so smoothly running in android app

Tags: java, android, xml

I have create some few of animation with running text on xml, and picture slideshow on java, but when I run my app all animation is not running smoothly. so what i can do to keep all animation running on my app is smooth. as my code below:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/trading"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="Trading Hours are Monday to Friday. 08:00 AM - 05:30 PM, welcome to Golden Royal Exchage and enjoy your game......"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="#ba8707"/>
```

Comment: yes, my code of running text is below. please advice.

Comment: before i add my picture slide show it running smoothly, but after i add my picture slide show it running not smooth

Comment: this is not your code, this is just the layout. How big is the image you're using on the slideshow?

Comment: my running text is run without java code, for the picture slide show is around 70k something...the picture slide show is ok, but only running text it not so smooth

Comment: which type of animation exactly you want......